# How to enrich my "everyday" vocabulary as an ESL parent in the U.S.?

Tags: pronunciation, vocabulary

How to quickly acquire the "everyday" English vocabulary needed to communicate with my preschool child?  I am an immigrant IT professional who speaks fluent English, but who learned his English as an adult.  My child is born in America.  I can easily communicate on work-related topics, especially in writing.  But when my child asks me "What is this?" or "What are you doing?", I often find myself at a loss.  For example, I am playing a tune by drumming with my feet, the child asks "What are you doing?" -- and I say "Err.. I am making music by..." [Hitting? No; Knocking? No; Stepping? With? Ugh...]  Instead of a single word, all I can offer is a lengthy explanation full of technical or generic terms or inadequate quasi-synonyms.  With other adults that had been OK, but not with a preschooler.  A related problem is figuring out pronunciation while reading children's books aloud.  I never heard these words spoken!  Is there some online resource, or a textbook, or a word/phrase list that I need to memorize?  Something more effective than writing out phrases by hand from hundreds of children's books?  Thanks!

Comment: You should speak to your child in your native tongue because you are the parent, that way your son/daughter will grow up to be bi-lingual.

Comment: I also think this question is better suited to a different [Stack Exchange site](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/) Your important question is not about a specific language problem but about effective communication between a parent and their child.

Comment: My child is 3-lingual and has a speech delay.  I use my native tongue, but I have to provide English input as well.

Comment: I think it is better asked in parenting stack exchange?

Comment: The speech delay is normal among children who are assimilating two or more languages, this will disappear in time and they will "code switch" from one language to the next with surprising and effortless ease. Be patient and forgiving with yourself (and don't stop speaking in your native language!)

Comment: @Mari-LouA In addition to Parenting SE, the question would also be a good fit on  [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network. But your child needs teaching by professionals. These include educationalists making TV programmes for children,  and good authors of childrens books (you can check why I've omitted the apostrophe some might want). There are CDs of these being read.

Comment: Excellent question but I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try watching something together like Dora the Explorer? Blues clues was my jam growing up, and frankly "kid's" programs aren't always that bad. Fun for both of you if you're watching the right one.